# jQuery does not detect current class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a JavaScript function where I change the class of a button (`<a href="..." class="button" id="placeOrdersButton">Button</a>`):

```
function showOrderButtonActive(isActive) {
        if (isActive) {
            $("#placeOrdersButton").addClass("button");
            $("#placeOrdersButton").removeClass("buttonDisabled");
        } else {
            $("#placeOrdersButton").removeClass("button");
            $("#placeOrdersButton").addClass("buttonDisabled");
        }
```

I also have a JavaScript function to show a loading panel when clicking on enabled buttons:

```
$("a:not([target='_blank'], [class='buttonDisabled'])").on("click", function (e) {
        window.LoadingPanel.Show();
    });
```

But when my JavaScript function changes the class to `buttonDisabled` it still shows the loading panel.

Why does jQuery not detect the current class name and how can I do this the best and most concise way?

Comment: Are you sure the second piece of code is called after the first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code is running like the following:

```
// [1] Retrieve all elements that match the selector *at the existing time*
$("a:not([target='_blank'], [class='buttonDisabled'])")

// [2] Attach a click event to those elements
.on("click", function (e) {
    window.LoadingPanel.Show();
});
```

So if an element's class changes, it doesn't affect the above code. The above code already ran and attached the events to the given elements.

One solution is [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), where you attach the event to a parent element and check the selector during the event:

```
// [1] Retrieve document
$(document)

// [2] Attach a click event to the document that will fire
//     if and only if the event started at or bubbled up through
//     the given selector
.on("click", "a:not([target='_blank'], [class='buttonDisabled'])", function (e) {
    window.LoadingPanel.Show();
});
```

Comment: `[class='buttonDisabled']` is a pointless selector that can be easily changed to standard css selector

Comment: There is a comma missing before "function..."